# Removing a function and adding it again

Tags: actionscript-3, function, flash-cs5

I know it's possible to add and remove functions via event listener, but I was curious to know if it's possible to add/remove a function not by event listener. So I guess a custom function

```
function timer(event:TimerEvent)
{
  example();
}

function example():void
{
  trace("example");
}
```

Would it be possible to remove the example function then add it again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you said, the common way is to use event listeners:

```
mytimer.removeEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, timer);
```

If you don't want to remove the listener you could use a flag to toggle `example` call:

```
var tick = false;
function timer(event:TimerEvent)
{
    if (tick) {
        example();
    }
}
```